# Nodejs zlib does not inflate the text it just deflated

Tags: node.js, zlib

I am using zlib.deflateRaw and zlib.inflateRaw to try to deflate a string and inflate it back again. however, the below process is throw error.

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const fs = require('fs');
let normal = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`;

zlib.deflateRaw(normal, function(err, deflated){
  console.log(deflated.toString('utf-8'));
});

let deflated = `�����Q(K-*��ϳU2�3PRH�K�O��K�U
qӵP��`;

zlib.inflateRaw(Buffer.from(deflated, 'utf-8'), function(err, inflated){
  console.log(err, inflated);
});
```

`defalted` is exactly what I copy/paste from the first `console.log` output. and i am getting `Error: invalid block type` error

Comment: deflated is a string ? Shouldnt it be a buffer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied and pasted?! Why would you expect that printing, copying, and pasting binary data would or possibly could preserve the actual byte values? Those white-in-black question marks are where the binary data is being corrupted.

To be able to copy and paste, you would need to convert the binary deflate output to something printable, e.g. with base64 conversion, and the convert it back before inflating.